# Do iptables support jitter simulation?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I'm using 14.04.1-Ubuntu.  I'm trying to find out if iptables supports creating jitter, like it does for packet loss. I'm using

```
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.02 -j DROP
```

to simulate packet loss, but can I do something similar to simulate jitter? I know TC will do it, but the firmware for our product does not support it. Using (TC) is OUT of the question.

I found some Perl module (I know little about Perl), that can simulate jitter for iptables. Would this be the way to go, by installing this module I found online (broker.pl) - or, is there already an exact iptables command, that can simulate jitter, that I do not know about?

I know nothing more about Linux, other than how to install it, and set up Apache. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: 14.04.1-Ubuntu, I added it to the question - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, iptables does not support jitter simulation.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answers are the best!  Upvoted!